# Nested Arguments or Object Arguments in storybook

Tags: storybook

I am trying out storybook version 6 against a vue.js set of components.

My components take objects as arguments, so I have a standard interface.

I can just pass in a block of json, but I like the arguments/controls interface for editing/selecting values.

Is it possible to configure arguments in storybook to be nested?

I have hacked it to build arguments with names objectname__fieldname, and then convert them in the object, but it is unsatisfactory from the documentation and ux perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did the same thing with the help of this https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat and it works now. I hope storybook would do something like this by default

Comment: There seem to be a couple of active Storybook issues looking at improving this: [Support destructuring object properties into individual controls](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12078) and [JSON Editor/Treeview for Object Properties](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12599).